# Referencing Ractive component's text

Tags: ractivejs

I want to enable a button when two text fields have length > 0: How do I refer to these text fields lengths to express this? Seems simple, but its not obvious to me how to refer to the component's and their text (length). I basically want to use FRP to enable/disable button for form submission. These would be "sibling" components I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two-way binding is an option, you could do something along these lines:

```html
<input value='{{foo}}'>
<input value='{{bar}}'>
<button disabled='{{ !foo || !bar }}'>submit</button>
```

This works because the empty string (`''`) is falsy in JavaScript, so `!foo || !bar` is only `false` when both `foo` and `bar` are non-empty.

Comment: it would not work if the user would type `0` in the input. http://jsfiddle.net/LqTWc/ since Ractive tries to convert to number if possible and `!0` is true.

Comment: How would I adjust/grab width/height so I could reactively re-layout div/children? I thought this was an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/ATAgH/, but its not modifying (or reacting to) actual width/height.

Comment: Good point @Codler! To avoid that I suppose you'd have to coerce values to a string e.g. `<button disabled='{{ !(''+foo) || !(''+bar) }}'>submit</button>`.

Comment: @Joel There's no way that I know of in JavaScript to be notified when a particular element's dimensions change. When I've had to solve similar problems in the past I generally add an event listener to the window's `resize` event. I've knocked up an example here - http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/63gjh/ - the resize handler could equally be created inside a component's `init()` method.

Comment: You guys rock! I'm surprised how quickly you respond.

Comment: IMHO, it would be really slick, if I could stick id's on the inputs, and refer to them accordingly: !inputOne.value || !inputTwo.value. I like it better because it just "feels" like I'm not prepping data so that I can use them elsewhere, rather just referring to them "as needed". Sounds like splitting hairs probably, but still I think the preferable split. Maybe not feasible, or maybe it already is possible?

Comment: It's not really feasible TBH - the reactivity works because we're saying (with `<input value='{{foo}}'>`) 'we want to observe the value of this input, because we're using it somewhere'. The other way round, we'd have to check every mustache, every expression, every `ractive.observe()` observer to see if they reference e.g. `inputOne` in order to add event listeners - very inefficient (or add event listeners regardless - also inefficient). And the change propagation mechanism would be the same anyway, it would just be 'hidden'. Moreover, using `id` attributes is bad for reusability.

Answer (score 0):

@Rich Harris: It seems that the problem with the `<button disabled="{{ !(''+foo) || !(''+bar) }}">submit</button>` trick is that the button is enabled at the start, because both `foo` and `bar` are initially `undefined` and `''+undefined` gives the string `'undefined'`.  The technique also becomes unwieldy if you have several fields with various validation requirements.

As you may know, Angular has a `$invalid` that you can apply to a form, e.g., `<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">submit</button>` where `myForm` is the form's `name` attribute.  In Ractive, I guess one could write an `isvalid` function and then use `<button disabled="{{ !isvalid() }}">submit</button>` but that only works for one form (or is there some way to "attach" it to a particular element?).