# Dynamic variable name binding

Tags: ractivejs

I have a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832275/referencing-ractive-components-text). But in my case a have dynamic amount of objects (posts) to bind so if I do it this way:

```
{{#each Posts}}
...
  {{#each Comments}}
  {{/each}}
  <form> /* new comment is added here */
    <textarea name="text" value="{{newCommentText}}" />
    <input type="submit" disabled="{{!newCommentText}}" />
  </form>
{{/each}}
```

the values of all textareas are synchronized. What I need is to somehow specify a unique variable name for each form (i. e. {{PostId_newCommentText}}). Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [restricted references](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/references#restricted-references) to add each new comment to the corresponding `Post`:

```html
{{#each Posts}}
    <form>
        <!-- .newCommentText === this.newCommentText -->
        <textarea name="text" value="{{.newCommentText}}" />
        <input type="submit" disabled="{{!.newCommentText}}" />
    </form>
{{/each}}
```

Another option is to use [`@index`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/mustaches#special-references) and store all new comments in separate array:

```html
{{#each Posts}}
    <form>
        <textarea name="text" value="{{NewComments[@index]}}" />
        <input type="submit" disabled="{{!NewComments[@index]}}" />
    </form>
{{/each}}
```

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mq197dox/).